# Monolithic Applications Horizontal Scalability (duplication) : how are database treated?

Tags: architecture, scalability, horizontal-scaling

sorry for the vague question but it is boggling my mind.
It is my understanding that a monolithic application can scale in two ways : vertically and horizontally. The latter involves duplicating the service by adding more copies of it. My doubts regards the role of databases in this type of approach.

Let's say, for example, I have an application A that connects to a database. Let's say I duplicate this application, and call the duplicate A'. Will A and A' share the same database, thus making it a possible for the database to become a bottleneck, or will A and A' have their own databases making it necessary to implement some mechanism to assure data consistency across the two instances of the database?

Comment: This needs a bit more clarification, what type of storage you're using, what type of load you have that you're thinking the DB may become the bottleneck?

Comment: Mavi I was wondering in general, eventually If you duplicate the application more than once it will become a bottleneck.  Now I have no clue whats kind of load would be required for that to happen but i'd guess it would. From your comment I'd say both approaches are possible favouring the applications using the same db?

Comment: A DB in this kind of design would be the bottleneck if you don't design for it. An example: if you have 2 nodes running the same app, one from US and other from EU and they are trying to connect to the same DB located in one of these locations, you're creating a problem.

Requirements really matter in this case. You should never have to implement the data consistency yourself, pretty much all decent storage systems offer you that. You should understand if you'll have more reads than writes, coming from a particular region / instance - if one failover is going to be sufficient etc...

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 approaches to horizontally scaling a database:

1. Use a database that provides inbuilt horizontal scaling. Eg: Cassandra, MongoD, etc.
2. Use application level logic to route traffic to appropriate database server. You basically take a set of users and divide them over multiple DB servers. So for example, you would typically have a "meta" database/table that would store clients, DB server/connection strings, etc and a table that stores client/server mapping. The app login/home screen will be common and will use data from this "meta" database. Once logged in or once you have info on who the use is, simply direct requests from each client to the DB server they are mapped to. i.e. you are using dynamic connection string based on the user.
   Instead of user you could decide to use some other criteria to horizontally partition your data.

Answer (score 0):

Databases are the source of truth in monolith applications. In other words, it is the "state" of your system. Hence, even if you have multiple instances, it makes sense to keep a single database (often resilient and high capacity) so that you have a single source of truth.

Of course real life is different. You can have slow queries due to scaling out. To combat this, there are multiple strategies. One of the most common strategies is to have multiple read databases and a single central write database. Write operaties are propogated to the read databases. Read databases can be configured to serve geographical areas. With this, the bottleneck worry is ironed out. Of course the "ironing out" is the real work to make this all happen.

In my view, it's not a good choice to have multiple databases as this goes against the principle of the state of truth (data inconsistency) in monolith systems. Also databases are expensive.